# Problem setting up static IP ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ip

I tried setting up a static IP firstly editing and adding a connection with no luck. Then I did [this][1]
Now the connection appears but the internet is not working. These are the steps I followed and my current configuration files:

```
jab@jab-Meerkat:~$ ifconfig -a
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ae:ed:78:3e:35  
          inet addr:192.168.1.34  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::533a:51cc:79e0:5436/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4777 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4933463 (4.9 MB)  TX bytes:669741 (669.7 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:aa100000-aa120000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:153808 (153.8 KB)  TX bytes:153808 (153.8 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:13:e8:40:32:b0  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

jab@jab-Meerkat:~$ ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s25  proto static  metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s25  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s25  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.34  metric 100 


jab@jab-Meerkat:~$ sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true


jab@jab-Meerkat:~$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s25 inet static
address 192.168.0.101
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

jab@jab-Meerkat:~$ sudo service network-manager restart
jab@jab-Meerkat:~$ sudo service networking restart
jab@jab-Meerkat:~$ sudo service resolvconf restart

jab@jab-Meerkat:~$ ifconfig
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ae:ed:78:3e:35  
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7511:ffb:7266:ce31/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:711 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:829 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:617772 (617.7 KB)  TX bytes:100534 (100.5 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:aa100000-aa120000
```

I also have rebooted the computer as after restarting the networking services and doing ifconfig the IP did not changed. Furthermore, after reboot was connected automatically to a dynamic IP, how? why? really don't know what is what I am missing. Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your file `/etc/network.interfaces` is wrong.

You have set your machine's IP address as `192.168.0.101`, and the gateway as `192.168.1.1`.

Your netmask is `255.255.255.0`, which means that the first three dotted decimals in the IP address define the network and the last one defines the machine.

This means that your gateway is on network `192.168.0.` and your machine is on network `192.168.1.`, so in effect the gateway and your computer are on different networks.

Guessing on your network setup, I think that you should change the address line to read `address 192.168.1.101`

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is working. The problem I've got now is that when I restart the system does not connect automatically and furthermore I cannot edit the connection in order to tick the box "automatically connect to this network when is available".  Also , why the connection is shown as ifupdown(enp0s25) instead of just enp0s25? Thank you!

Comment: @Jab that's because NetworkManager ignores interfaces that are defined via the `/etc/network/interfaces` file (they configure different *services*). If you want to be able to edit/manage the interface via the NetworkManager GUI, then you should revert your file changes and configure the interface via the GUI.

Comment: I've tried that the problem is that the GUI shows device not managed.  I also tried to add the following line in /etc/network/interfaces: auto enp0s25. The problem is that for some reason my computer names the conection ifupdow(enp0s25). I also tried to remove ifupdow  in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf so it reads plugins=keyfile,ofono instead of plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono. The result is that the connection stops working. Any idea why the computer names my connection ifupdown( enp0s25)? Thanks!

Comment: If you want `/etc/network/interfaces` to control, then you need to change Network Manager to `managed=false`. Reboot and test.

Comment: I tried earlier on and also now again and when I reboot de GUI shows "device not managed".  The wired network does not show when ifconfig. Thanks!